# how to get onclick value from a component to other component in angular 10

Tags: angular

I have 2 components, I want to get the value from test to Product component onclick a button from test component. I am already getting the value using EventEmitter. But its copying whole content of test component including background color,I need only value.Here is the code

### test.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showName()">Submit</button>
<div style="height:300px;width:100%;background:red">Hello</div>
```

### test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
@Output() buttonClicked = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() name:string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
 showName(){
    this.name = "My value"
    this.buttonClicked.emit(this.name);
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

### product.component.html

```
<div><app-test (buttonClicked)='showNextComponent($event)'></app-test></div>
```

### product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
showNextComponent(name:string) {
    console.log(name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Try explicity giving EventEmitter a type with 
@Output()  buttonClicked = new EventEmitter<string>();

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: try to pass only string (I mean only 'my value') rather than `this.name`, to make sure that you are passing correct value..

Comment: Ya try passing "test" just for this time. See what happens?

Comment: Odds are that "this." is pointing to your test component

Comment: this.buttonClicked.emit('My value'); , still same issue

Answer (score 0):

you can use the angular service for pass the data from one component to another

firstly create the data service as follows

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  name="";

  constructor() { }
}
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './service/dataservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showName(){
    this.dataService.name = "My value";
  }
}
```

product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './service/dataservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showNextComponent() {
     console.log(this.dataService.name);
  }
}
```

product.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary (click)="showNextComponent()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: But I want to get this name onclick of a button

Comment: yep, click event of button (in test.component.html file) set value to `name` variable in the data.service.ts. then you can access this variable from product.component.ts using `showNextComponent` method

Comment: in this case I need to use this in product component html right ? <app-test (buttonClicked)='showNextComponent($event)'></app-test>

Comment: button click event in product.component.html call to `showNextComponent` method in your product.component.ts file. in this time you can access `name` ( variable's value is `My value`) variable from DataService as above answer

Comment: But it will populate all contents of test.component.html, if I am using background color (<div style="height:300px;width:100%;background:red">Hello</div>) in test component html,that will also come in product component. I need only value instead of all contents

Comment: did you try above solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233839/discussion-between-lakshan-and-uiappdeveloper).

Comment: please change the product.component.html as per the modified answer

Answer (score 0):

Following approach might resolve your issue:

In the product component typescript, you have to create a method to receive the value of the `name` variable like this:

```
export class ProductComponent {

constructor() { }

name: string;

receiveStringValue($event) {
  this.name= $event;
 }
}
```

In product component html, put the following:

```
<app-test (stringValueEvent)="receiveStringValue($event)"></app-test>
<h1>{{name}}<h1>
```

In test component html, put the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showName()">Submit</button>
<div *ngIf="!name">
  <div style="height:300px;width:100%;background:red">Hello</div>
</div>
```

In the test component typescript (app-test selector), you should declare a `stringValueEvent` variable with the `@Output()` decorator and set it equal to a new event emitter.

```
export class TestComponent {

  name: string = "";

  @Output() stringValueEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {        
  }

  showName(): void{
    this.name = "My value";
    this.stringValueEvent.emit(this.name);
  }      
}
```

Comment: Not working , same issue , I need on click , here it is ngOnInit

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER, answer has been edited. Could you please try now if it works?

Comment: Still same issue, getting all contents of test component , you just put this in test.component.html <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showName()">Submit button</button>
<div style="height:300px;width:100%;background:red">Hello</div> , every thing is fine but I don't want this div section to show in product component

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER, answer is edited. Please try now. Hope it would work now :)

Comment: Still I am getting the contents of test component

Comment: I fixed it using *ngIf="router.url !== '/product'"  in test component html

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER, its great that you have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Test' component is the child component from where you need to pass your value to parent component 'Product'.

Your value 'name' is not coming from Parent, it will be generated somewhere in Child component only.

So just change your code in Test component from:

```
@Input() name:string;
```

to

```
name:string;
```

Comment: getting same issue

Comment: Can you please provide stackbiltz of your code with the issue. I tried but I am not able to reproduce your issue. I am getting the correct string value.